# Conditional TSQL Grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to craft a TSQL statement that will group album and and artists and sort by artist name. Each track has all of the ID3 data with album and artist names. When certain albums have more than one artist, the sort order gets messed up.

How do I conditionally group artists as "Various Artists" when the artist names don't match but the album names do?

Here is my simplified TSQL statement:

```
SELECT songid, artist, album, tracknumber 
FROM mp3
ORDER BY artist, album, tracknumber
```

If it matters this is Microsoft SQL Server that I'm working in.

Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: i presume you're sql server 2008 and above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but the general idea should be apparent nonetheless...

The same expression that is used for the AlbumArtist field can be used for grouping.

```
WITH
   VariousArtistsCTE
   AS
   (SELECT
      album,
      CASE WHEN 
         COUNT(DISTINCT Artist) = 1
      THEN
         0
      ELSE
         1
      END AS VariousArtists
   FROM mp3
   GROUP BY album)

SELECT
   songid,
   artist AS TrackArtist,
   album,
   tracknumber
   CASE WHEN va.VariousArtists = 1 THEN 'Various Artists'
   ELSE artist END As AlbumArtist 
FROM
   mp3
LEFT OUTER JOIN
   VariousArtistsCTE va
   ON mp3.Album = va.Album
```

Comment: Will I have to pass this as a stored procedure or is there a way to execute this as a consolidated SELECT? Thank you for the reply. This is very helpful.

Comment: You can execute this as it is, as a select statement. The CTE (`WITH ..` requires SQL 2005 or later, and if there is any SQL ahead of this, you need to add a semi-colon before the `WITH` keyword. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx